# want to store date output in variable

Tags: shell, scripting, date, echo

i tried the below code to store the date output in variable.

```
read -p 'date: ' mydate
date_month= date -d "$mydate" +%b
echo $date_month
```

it is not printing the output.
how to store the date output in variable?.

Answer (score 1):

Your script as written contains

```
date_month= date -d "$mydate" +%b
```

Note the space.  This runs `date -d "$mydate" +%b` with `date_month` set to an empty string.  In order to put the result of this command in the variable, you have to use command substitution:

```
date_month=$(date -d "$mydate" +%b)
```

Note also the lack of a space.